# Intel XDK / Cordova device back button always close app after build

Tags: android, cordova, back-button, intel-xdk

I have a custom script for the device backbutton event and it works perfectly on Intel XDK debug and Intel AppPreview.

The problem is, after building the project and installing the .apk, pressing the backbutton always completely closes the app, regardless of the script (already have tried e.preventDefault and return false, didn't help)

I've searched and didn't found any similar problem, usually people have this problem when debugging or previewing the app, not on the built .apk.

Comment: Found an answer yet?

Comment: You are use angularjs + ionic?

Comment: Not yet. The initial project provided to me calls ionic.bundle.js, and inside the ionic folder there are ionic-angular.js and a angular folder, so I guess it's been used also.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Plus, as I mentioned I already tried preventing the 'backbutton' event.